# Multiple field Indexing in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I am trying to apply indexing for my mongodb collection through pymongo. I am using

`db[collection_name].ensure_index([("field_name" , "text"),("unique", 1), ("dropDups" , 1)])`

and it works. But now how can apply it for multiple fields?
Something like this

`db[collection_name].ensure_index([("field_name1" , "text"),("field_name2", "text"),("field_name3", "text"),("unique", 1), ("dropDups" , 1)])`

I know we can use `db.collection.ensureIndex({"$**":"text"},{"name":"TextIndex"})`
 in mongo shell but I dont want to Index all the fields. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: you want a composite index, or separate indexes on the required text fields?

Comment: I want to do Composite/Compound indexing through python script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from pymongo import IndexModel, ASCENDING, DESCENDING
>>> index1 = IndexModel([("hello", DESCENDING),
...                      ("world", ASCENDING)], name="hello_world")
```

This was mentioned in the doc for pymongo

```
db[collection_name].create_index([("field_name1" , TEXT),("field_name2", TEXT)],name="index_name"))
```

This will provide a composite index on [field_name1,field_name2]

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_indexes

Comment: db[collection_name].ensure_index([("field_name1" , TEXT),("field_name2", TEXT),("field_name3",TEXT)],("unique", 1), ("dropDups" , 1)) when used it gave me TypeError: ensure_index() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given). But when i used db[collection_name].ensure_index([("field_name1" , TEXT),("field_name2", TEXT)],name="index_name")) it worked! thanks..

Answer (score 4):

Straight from [the doc of `createIndex`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index):

```
>>> my_collection.create_index([("field_name1", TEXT),
...                             ("field_name2", TEXT),
                                unique=True,
                                dropDups=1])
```

Beware that:

> `dropDups` is not supported by MongoDB 2.7.5 or newer. The option is silently ignored by the server and unique index builds using the option will fail if a duplicate value is detected.

Anyway, this will create a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) on `field_name1` and `field_name2`.

Finally, please notice there are some limitation when using [compound text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index) though.

Comment: I think, you took it wrong, "unique" here is not a field, its for the uniqueness of the composite index.

Comment: @Nishant How silly am I... Thank you for your comment !

Comment: :) no worries  19K rock